# Why doesn't universal reference apply for arrays?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void f(const T&)
{
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<T>); // ok
}

template<typename T>
void g(T&&)
{
    static_assert(std::is_array_v<T>); // error
}

int main()
{
    char arr[8];
    f(arr); // ok
    g(arr); // error
}
```

My compiler is clang 7.0 with `-std=c++17`.

**Why doesn't universal reference apply for arrays?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, these are officially called *"forwarding references"*, not  *"universal references"*.

Your `static_assert` fails due to the fact that `T` is deduced as `T&` when passing an lvalue to a function taking a *"forwarding reference"* - this is one of the special rules of *"forwarding references"* that apply during template argument deduction.

You can fix your assert by stripping any reference out first:

```
static_assert(std::is_array_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>>);
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ixzodH)

---

[`std::remove_cvref_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref) is a bleeding edge C++20 feature - you might want to use `std::remove_reference_t` instead if your compiler doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant rule here when the [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) takes place is:

> **Deduction from a function call**
>   ...
>   4. If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, **the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction.**

So in your case, `arr` is being deduced as **reference to** `arr` and thus the `static_assert` fails.